# How to create a UIButton programmatically

Tags: swift, uibutton

I am trying to build `UIView`s **programmatically**. How do I get a `UIButton` with an action function in Swift?

The following code does not get any action:

```
let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(100, 400, 100, 50))
btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
btn.setTitle("Click Me", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btn.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(buttonPuzzle)
```

The following selector function is:

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    var btnsendtag: UIButton = sender
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're just missing which `UIButton` this is. To compensate for this, change its `tag` property.
Here is you answer:

```
let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(100, 400, 100, 50))
btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
btn.setTitle("Click Me", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btn.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
btn.tag = 1               // change tag property
self.view.addSubview(btn) // add to view as subview
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 400, width: 100, height: 50))
btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
btn.setTitle(title: "Click Me", for: .normal)
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .touchUpInside)
btn.tag = 1               
self.view.addSubview(btn)
```

Here is an example selector function:

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    var btnsendtag: UIButton = sender
    if btnsendtag.tag == 1 {            
        //do anything here
    }
}
```

Comment: If sender.tag == 1 { ... }

Answer (score 9):

Using a tag is a fragile solution. You have a view and you are creating and adding the button to that view, you just need to keep a reference to it: For example

**In your class, keep a reference to the button**

```
var customButton: UIButton!
```

**Create the button and set the reference**

```
let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 400, width: 100, height: 50))
btn.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
btn.setTitle("Click Me", forState: .Normal)
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyClass.buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(btn)
customButton = btn
```

**Test against this instance in the action function**

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    guard sender == customButton else { return }

    // Do anything you actually want to do here
}
```

Comment: Very minor, but you forgot the space after `btn` and before `=` here: `let btn= UIButton...`

Answer (score 1):

You have to **addSubview** and **tag** on that **btn**.